# How would I handle "sub strings?" JSON files using java?

Tags: java, json

I'm not sure if "complex JSON" is the right terminology.

I'm trying to go through the text in this JSON

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson

When handling the simple stuff like metadata generated I do something like this:

```
  JSONObject x = JSONObject.fromObject(JSonString);
  JSONObject petData = (JSONObject) (x.get("metadata"));

  System.out.println(petData.get("generated"));
```

But when I tried doing more complicated stuff like finding the features: 0: type: I couldn't get it to work. None of the examples I found have included something like this. Where it has more than one step to get to it. Also, if you know the actual name for JSON files that do this instead of me just calling that complex that'd be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with marshalling and unmarshalling, it is always good to have a POJO model defined. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
class GeoResponse {
   private String type;
   private Metadata metadata;
   private List<Feature> features;

   // so on
   // getters and setters
}

class Metadata {
   private String generated;
   private String url;
   // so on
   // getters and setters
}
class Feature {
   private String id;
   private String type;
   private Properties properties;
   // so on
}
// so on
```

Parse JSON to your object with [Jackson Mapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
GeoResponse data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, GeoResponse.class);
```

Now you can easily access the fields you want. For example:

```
Metadata metadata = data.getMetadata();
// ...and so on
```